# Can all permutations of a set or string be generated in O(n log n) time?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was looking over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352203/2327689) requesting an algorithm to generate all permutations of a given string. A comment in the answer caught my eye:

*It might seem that it can take O(n) time per permutation, but if you think about it more carefully, you can prove that it takes only O(n log n) time for all permutations in total, so only O(1) -- constant time -- per permutation.*

This seemed strange to me because the best method I was aware of to generate all permutations of a string is in O(2^n) time. Looking through the other results, I came across a [response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7140205/2327689) which states: *While it technically produces the desired output, you're solving something that could be O(n lg n) in O(n^n)*

I am aware of an algorithm to unrank permutations in O(n log n) time, but these responses seem to imply that all permutations in total can be generated in time O(n log n). Am I misunderstanding these responses?

Comment: According to [c++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) his claim is wrong, because is half of a distance of first and last, which is $\Theta(n)$ in average, but the worse thing is your interpretation, the function that described in the SO link is *next-permutation*, not all permutation, and I think because of this bad interpretation others answered you is $O(n!)$, edit your question and make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the SO question itself (or we have misinterpreted yours, which seems more likely). That SO quesiton is talking about generating a 'next' permutation from a previous given one, so that all permutations can be generated by calling 'next' multiple times.

The answer to that is talking about the (amortized) time complexity of the C++ implementation `std::next_permutation` which I believe uses [Narayana Pandita's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order), and generates them in lexicographic order.

(Also, as an aside: permutations are different from combinations. There are $n!$ permutations, but $2^n$ combinations (subsets). You seem to be under the impression that permutation is same as a combination (based on your claim of $O(2^n)$)).

To get back to the original question, another way to look at the question: would using `next_permutation` to generate all the $n!$ permutations in lexicographic order be $\Theta(n!)$ or $\Theta(n\times n!)$?

While there are some wrong statements in the answer you linked, it does state the right answer: It is $\Theta(n!)$, i.e. the amortized time complexity of `next_permutation` is indeed $O(1)$.

This can be proven as follows:

If $T(n)$ is the time taken to generate all the $n!$ permutations using `next_permutation` then we have that

$$T(n) = n T(n-1) + O(n^2)$$

(You fix the first number $n$ times and generate the permutations for the rest, and pay $O(n)$ cost when the first number is switched.)

Let $G(n) = \dfrac{T(n)}{n!}$. Note that we are looking the the asymptotics of $G(n)$. We get

$$G(n) \le G(n-1) + \frac{cn^2}{n!}$$

This is a simple telescoping sum, and since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{n!}$ is convergent, we get that

$$G(n) = O(1)$$

Note that you could have changed the recursion to

$$T(n) = nT(n-1) + O(n^k)$$

and still have gotten $O(1)$ amortized per permutation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is impossible. There are $n!$ permutations of a string of $n$ characters, which is vastly more than $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Accessing all permutations will take O(n!) time, but does this hold for generation as well? Say you have a sequence 1,2,...,n. This can be represented as a forest with n! nodes. But there are redundancies in the forest; for example, the tree under the nodes 1->2 is exactly the same as the tree under the nodes starting 2->1. The redundancy can be eliminated by simply linking the two nodes together, without ever visiting the permutations for the second tree. I was curious if, based on the linked questions, an algorithm existed in O(n log n) time. (Perhaps I am misinterpreting the answers.)

Comment: @SamVernalis what does "generation" mean?

Answer (score 2):

generating permutations has complexity $O(N!)$ it means that we do $O(1)$ per permutation
I dont know why you think that to generate is less than accessing but in this problem we have a mathematical proof why you need at least $N!$

Comment: As I wrote in the answer above, given a sequence 1,2,...,n, the set of all permutations can be represented as a tree with n! nodes. But the child tree of the nodes 1->2, for example, is the same as the child tree of the nodes 2->1, so you can link the two child trees to prevent having to generate them twice. The total number of nodes is equal to the total number of combination trees, which is equal to the total of the binomial coefficients, which has the closed form 2^n. This of course is just an example of how to generate them quicker than accessing them, as the time is O(2^n).

Comment: then you need $O(2^n!)$ not $n!$ because every leaf is a permutation , and in order to fill this space you must have at least to run $O(2^n!)$!

Comment: I see the comments and they wrote that they generate them in $O(nlogn)$ in $O(n^n)$ which means that the time complexity is:$O(n^n*log(n^n)=O(n^{n+1} log(n))$

Comment: In the algorithm I explained above, I am talking strictly about generating permutations. Reading these permutations would of course take O(n!) time. The number of nodes, however, would be O(2^n), as, for example, all permutations of (3,4,5) beneath (1,2) and (2,1) are the same, so the 1->2 and 2->1 nodes link to the same sub-tree.

Comment: this [paper](http://www.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf) talks about **all** permutation generation algorithms